# vscode, how can binding to a key/or automatically, for a delete lines empties?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In sublime text 3, I have a shortcut to delete lines, format and save.

```
//reindent and save
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+s"],
    "command": "chain",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            ["delete_empty_lines"],
            ["reindent",{"single_line": false}],
            ["save"]
        ]
    }
},
```

But in vscode I have to use the function to replace the expression with:

```
ctrl + h
\n\n
to
empty
```

Does it have another similar way for vscode, as in sublime text 3?

Answer (score 0):

As of VSCode 1.15, such a chain of commands would have to be contributed by an extension. There are a few extensions in the marketplace that already add support for this:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=giyyapan.commander

Or you can [try writing a custom extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview).

We are tracking built-in support for chaining commands [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6617)